# .Net Core Connection currently has transaction enlisted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, .net-core, mstest

I'm writing Integration Test using .Net Core 2.1  I have a test which looks like so:

```
private TransactionScope scope;

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
    this.scope.Dispose();
}

[TestInitialize]
public void VerifyUsersHaveBeenSeeded()
{
    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions { 
             IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted 
    };
    //I've also tried using TransactionScopeOption.Required
    this.scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                     transactionOptions);
}

//Note I am using an MDF file during Testing.
protected AstootContext GetContext()
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AstootContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.ASTOOT_CONNECTION_STRING);
    var context = new AstootContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    return context;
}


[TestMethod]
public async Task RestEzServiceVerifyUpdate()
{
    var context = this.GetContext();
    var expectedResult = context.Users.First();

    var restEzService = GetDefaultService<User, UserDTO>(context);
    var key = new object[] { expectedResult.Id };

    var dto = await restEzService.Get(key);

    var updatedName = "Updated";
    dto.FirstName = updatedName;

    var updatedDTO =  await restEzService.Update(key, dto);
    Assert.IsTrue(updatedDTO.FirstName == updatedName);
    updatedDTO.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResult, 
        o => o.Excluding(x => x.UniqueIdentifier).Excluding(x => x.FirstName));

    context.Dispose();
}
```

The update method calls:

```
var entity = await this._context.FindAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
this.applyDTOToEntity(entity, dto);
await this._context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When It calls save changes I get an Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Connection currently has transaction enlisted.  Finish current transaction and retry.

The only places I call from the context is 1. To get the expected result in the test, 2. Get the Updated Entity, 3. To Save changes.

I have the transactionScopeOptions set to Requires New, Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you create new DbContext into Update method?

Comment: No it’s passed into the service

Comment: Add GetContext method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` tries to create new transaction. Are you sure, that there is no transaction at the point `new TransactionScope`.

Maybe, you need to replace it with `TransactionScopeOption.Required`

Also you use async/await, so add to scope option `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled`:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(... ,
  TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
```

Comment: I just changed the scope options to use Required, it has the same behavior

Comment: @johnny5 check if `Transaction.Current` is null before creating new scope

Comment: When I go to save Transaction.Current is null, Also I've Isolated the problem even more so that It only calls update, so that it only calls the db to get then entity, and to call `SaveChanges`

Comment: @johnny5 try `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` option, updated answer

Comment: Thanks thats was the cause

Comment: @johnny5 glad to help!

Comment: Fixed me too. Found this page which summarises the option clearly: https://particular.net/blog/transactionscope-and-async-await-be-one-with-the-flow